# Tkinter image doesn't show up

Tags: python, tkinter

Why won't the following code work:

```
root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=1500, height=1500)


def createTank(x, y):
    tank = PhotoImage(file="Game/tank.gif")
    canvas.create_image(x, y, image=tank) 
    canvas.pack()

createTank(500, 500)
root.mainloop()
```

When running the code, I simply get a blank tkinter window. Why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=1500, height=1500)
canvas.pack()
tank = PhotoImage(file="Game/tank.gif")

def createTank(x, y):
    canvas.create_image(x, y, image=tank)

createTank(500, 500)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to move your code out of the function as it will work in the global scope. With a function the image object may get garbage-collected when the function exits, which will cause the label to appear blank.
There's an easy workaround (save a persistent reference to the image object), but the point of the above code is to show the simplest code possible.

Try structuring your code as follows:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
image = tk.PhotoImage(file="Game/tank.gif")
label = tk.Label(image=image)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```